# Rails - is writing tests for testing CRUD operations worth it, if so integration or unit?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a lengthy but simple form which allows users to update products, nothing fancy, just displays the fields to enter mostly text values & then updates the corresponding database table.

Is it regular practice to write tests for CRUD operations such as this? Its important the form works properly as it will be used everyday - however there is really not much to go wrong. I have the time to do this, but don't want to be wasting time either or make future maintenance of my test suite overly difficult.

If I was to cover this with tests, should I use integration (cucumber) or unit (rspec) tests?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory I believe you are supposed to use both: Rspec to test each layer in isolation, then Cucumber to test the whole stack. But if you think this piece of your app is too straight-forward to warrent slavish adherence to those principles,  I would recommend you stick with the integration tests. It's important to know if something isn't working right, and IMO Cucumber alone should be suffient for that purpose.

Of course for more complex areas of your app, you probably want to use some mixture of each.